Unable to upload file to server in react-native
I've been trying to upload a file (Encrypted DJI Log file) to a server in order to decrypt it. All of this within my react native expo app.
I have not managed to get the server to accept my file when trying to send a fetch request in the app. I keep getting the following error:
500 Internal Server Error
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "isError": true,
  "responseException": {
    "exceptionMessage": "Unhandled Exception occurred. Unable to process the request."
  }
}

The working samples below prove that it is not the server itself being the issue, but rather the way I upload the file.
I have managed to succeed in sending successful requests in a Node.js environment while testing out the API, but the switch to react seemed impossible. Here are 2 ways I did manage to get a successful response, but fist of all, here is the official (working) example provided in the API documentation (https://www.flightreader.com/api/documentation/):
DOC Example (works)
<html>

<body>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput">
    <br><br>
    <div id="output"></div>

    <script>
        // Replace with your Flight Reader API secret key
        const secretApiKey = "sk_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        // Note: You should never expose your API secret key like this in a production environment.
        //       Anyone who has access to it will be able to make API requests on your behalf.

        // Call the "/api/v1/fields" endpoint to see a complete list of log fields that can be set here
        const fields = ["OSD_FlyTimeMilliseconds", "OSD_Latitude", "OSD_Longitude"];

        async function processFlightLog() {
            try {
                const formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("file", fileInput.files[0]);

                // Remove this forEach loop if you'd like to retrieve all available fields
                fields.forEach((value, index) => {
                    formData.append("fields", value);
                });

                const response = await fetch("https://api.flightreader.com/v1/logs", {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: formData,
                    headers: {
                        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
                        "Authorization": `Bearer ${secretApiKey}`
                    }
                });

                if (response.ok) {
                    const blob = await response.blob();
                    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    const link = document.createElement("a");

                    link.href = url;
                    link.setAttribute("download", "DJIFlightRecord.csv");
                    link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
                    document.body.appendChild(link);
                    link.click();

                    output.textContent = "CSV file successfully downloaded";
                } else {
                    output.textContent = `${response.status} ${response.statusText}`;
                }
            } catch (error) {
                output.textContent = error;
            }
            finally {
                fileInput.value = null;
            }
        }

        fileInput.addEventListener("change", () => {
            output.textContent = "Processing flight log file...";

            processFlightLog();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>

I have attempted to recreate the following process in Node.js, and here are 2 methods that did work.

(Works)

import { LocalFileData, constructFileFromLocalFileData } from "get-file-object-from-local-path";
import * as fs from "fs";

async function processLog() {
    try {
        const fileData = new LocalFileData('path_to_log.txt');
        const file = constructFileFromLocalFileData(fileData);
        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("file", file);


        const response = await fetch("https://api.flightreader.com/v1/logs", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
            headers: {
                "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${s_key}`
            }
        });
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log("Success!");
            const responseText = await response.text();
            fs.writeFileSync('response.txt', responseText);
        }
        else {
            const errorText = await response.text();

            console.log(`${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
            console.log(errorText);
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

Here is the referenced NPM package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-file-object-from-local-path

(Works)

import * as fs from "fs";
import axios, * as others from 'axios';
import FormData from 'form-data';
const {getHeaders} = FormData

async function processLog2() {

    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', fs.createReadStream('path_to_log.txt'));
    console.log(form.getHeaders())
    axios.post('https://api.flightreader.com/v1/logs', form, {
        headers: {
            ...form.getHeaders(),
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${s_key}`   
        },
    })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('File uploaded successfully:', response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
        });
}

Now, I am aware that "fs" and "get-file-object-from-local-path" are node-specific packages that do not work in the react-native environment. However, I believe the problem is not the reading of the files themselves, but rather the way the "packages" and sent to the server.
Within my RN app, I have tried multiple combinations of headers, like setting content-types, and others. Mainly using the (rn-fetch-blob)[https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob] library.
Here is one of my iterations: (Not working)
async function decryptLog(logFile: DocumentPickerAsset) {
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', await RNFetchBlob.fs.readStream(logFile.uri,"base64"));
    try {
    const res = await axios.post('https://api.flightreader.com/v1/logs', form, {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${s_key}`   
        },
    })}
    catch (err) {
        console.log
    }

}

Finally, here is some information about the file trying to be uploaded received thanks the the file -I file command: dji_log.txt: application/octet-stream; charset=binary

There is an example to upload a file in multipart in the github page of rn-fetch-blob : https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob?tab=readme-ov-file#user-content-multipartform-data-example--post-form-data-with-file-and-data - Else, you have many examples on Stack Overflow of people uploading files using ReactNative, like these ones : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38712952/6270743 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/44069378/6270743 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/36124650/6270743 . Did you try one/some of them ?
